# Full version of CPLEX sofware

Tags: cplex

I  try the BM ILOG CPLEX Optimization for my thesis, but the data is too large for it. My data have a lot lines. After running, I got "Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: CPLEX Error 1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded" and it asked me to buy another version. However, its too costly for 1 time use. So now, anyone can help me to find a full version that i can run my data?

Someone that help me to solve my problem in CPLEX software full version and send the output of my code.

Comment: So if I understand it right you want someone to help you pirate software licences? Aside from that, from what I understand that software has free academic licence.

Comment: Absolutely not, I have the academic version of the software. It is expensive for me to pay that much for the full version for one time use and I would be happy if someone could run the code for me and send me the output.

Answer (score 1):

if you are an academic you can use the free academic version that is not restricted. If you are not you can use free cloud credit to run your models.

See [what is free with CPLEX](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer/)

Comment: Thanks Alex,
I work for hours on the code and I only manage to run when I divide the problem into two.
Can you help me run the problem? Maybe just send me an output if you succeed?
Thanks